# Users continue adding/removing a specific tag

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

I just noticed these two users: [Pimgd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540837/pimgd?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and [M. A. Kishawy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146197/m-a-kishawy?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

The first one makes one suggested edit after the other one removing the [spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spawn) tag (what sometimes make sense), the other one suggests edits where he adds the [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) tag (that really isn't related to any of the questions).

What should I do with those users?

Comment: Adding the IBM tag to questions about WebSphere tags is superfluous IMO; so I suggest rejecting those with "irrelevant tags".

Comment: @S.L.Barth Best thing is that he removed the websphere tag in one of his suggested edits

Comment: To their credit, user @pimgd does more than just changing tags now: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6038212 .

Comment: @S.L.Barth Sometimes, but sometimes there is only the tag removed: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6037857

Comment: sound like [Nu, pogodi!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nu,_pogodi!)

Comment: I always wondered: why aren't user notified when they're the subject of a discussion on meta? I don't find it fair to be under trial if you can't even write a sentence to defend yourself.

Comment: Heh... Trial... defend yourself... you don't want to write a sentence! Sentences are a bad outcome for the defendant! I know how it works, I've seen Law and Order.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The question we reviewers should ask is: does the tag add value?

In the case of the IBM tag, most of the time it doesn't; in fact, [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm) is probably a meta-tag. Most if not all of these edit suggestions can be rejected with "invalid tags".

In the case of the [spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spawn) tag, these edit suggestions are correct - the tag wiki excerpt clearly says it's about child processes, and the user is removing it from things like spawning enemies in games.

We've had the "Too Minor" reject reason for a long time, and I guess many of us are still used to rejecting very minor edits. It probably doesn't help that these very minor edits will still be rewarded with +2 rep if they get accepted.

But ultimately our goal is not determine who deserves rep and who doesn't; our goal is to keep the site clean.

So minor edits that are correct, should not be rejected. 
If you don't want to approve them, skip them; chances are some robo-reviewers will eventually let them through, leaving you a slot to reject a worse edit.

Comment: But whats with the `Reject and Edit` button? Shouldn't I hit that and do the edit myself, so that nobody earns rep for that?

Comment: @msrd0 SE will not want us to use that button just to keep someone from getting rep; use it if your edit is significantly better. (And maybe post a feature-request to not give rep for tag-only edits...?)

Comment: Okay, so if I also add a `<!-- language: lang-X -->` tag (that was needed) should I use that button? And thanks for the tip, I'll post an feature-request therefore

Comment: @msrd0 It really depends on how stern you want to be. If SE has a position on it, it's probably "if you leave the tag, that proves it was a minor but good edit".

Comment: @S.L.Barth citation on what SE wants?

Comment: @msrd0 Reject bad edits, where bad means "not improving or actively harming the post". That's it. Even if all the user does is capitalize the first letter of a sentence, that improved the post, so accept it. If you think there's even more to do to help the post, accept and edit. But don't reject out of a misplaced feeling that you should decide who deserves to get rep and who doesn't.

Answer (score 28):

I went on a tag clean-up for [spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spawn) after seeing it being not used properly. I previously did such a thing on Super User: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8649/cleaning-gigabyte-tag

There they said that I don't need to make a question for it.

Now, Super User is not Stack Overflow, I realize that now. But still. Should I have posted a question here?

After the first reject, I felt bad - I probably had 15 edits in queue and if the rest of them get declined too I'd have an edit ban. I don't want to get an edit ban; not being able to fix things that are WRONG just hurts.

So I went fixing other things that I found alongside cleaning the tags. This made it take longer, but it's done now.

... as for the reputation, yes, I have an ulterior motive there. I wish I'd reach 2k rep so I can make the small edits without bothering anyone. I've had that privilege on Code Review for a while now and cleaning typos as you read posts is one of the best things ever. Then I come back to Stack Overflow and I have to ignore all the typos because I'll get stung with a minimum character limit for edits.

Comment: I can fully understand you, and retaggings are needed, but IMO they are Too Minor. As I had below 2k rep (and its not that long ago), I also tried to make the post as good as I could, and if you look back in your hierarchy, you'll see that I accepted the ones that only needed retagging

Comment: And retagging has one problem: If you retag old questions, they come to the front page, and SO has enough questions with new activity, so that I only retag old questions with  very many upvotes

Comment: @msrd0 as mentioned in the other answer... the too-minor reason for rejecting edits is gone. If you find such edits in the queue (and they are good edits) you should improve them, and not reject them... Additionally, mistaggings should be cleaned up, regardless of votes or question age IMO....

Comment: @Vogel612 Yes, I noticed that, and I posted this question because I wanted to know how to handle those suggested edits (mostly the one adding the [tag:ibm] tag randomly)

Comment: @msrd0 I believe your mindset about minor edits is a bit wrong headed. If an edit makes the site a better place, why reject it? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/?cb=1

Comment: @RubberDuck Of course this is also a bit opinion based, and sorry if I repeat me but I asked this question to know how I should continue with those edits

Comment: The plural of typo is typos.

Comment: @AirThomas No, it's "typi".

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I thought it was "code"?

Comment: Please don't go on a tag-cleaning spree unless you have the rep to edit posts without the need of review... you'll create massive amounts of work for everyone. If you edit 20 posts you involve up to 100 people in edit reviews. I'd post a burninate-request here on SO meta instead and hope someone with high rep and/or a moderator will fix it instead.

Comment: @Lundin burninate is for when you want the tag gone. I don't want the tag gone. I want to carefully go over each question that has a certain tag, and remove it if not needed. That's a lot of work to ask from other people. Why can't I do it myself, and then have others only needing to verify the questions I've found where the tag needs to go?

Comment: "not being able to fix things that are WRONG just hurts" +1