# Don't let users earn rep for retagging-only suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, tags, suggested-edits

I often see suggested edits that only retaggs questions. Normally they are correct, but I think they are a too minor to accept them. Since there is no Too Minor option anymore, and I don't think that SE wants me to enter "Too Minor" in the "Causes Harm" box, I have no choice to Approve them (See also [Users continue adding/removing a specific tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274868/users-continue-adding-removing-a-specific-tag)).

So can we maybe stop users earn reputation for retagging-only edits? I mean they are good and needed, and helps the site, but IMO they are Too Minor to be worth +2 rep.

Comment: +1. I see too many tag-only edits that are dubious at best. I don't think tag-only edits need being incentivized like they are now.

Comment: I don't think I'd have bothered cleaning up the tags for old questions if I didn't get rep for it. It boils down to whether you want tags cleaned or not. Maybe I'd retag for the questions in my area of expertise, but random questions? Nah.

Comment: how about cases where a re-tag is all that a question needs? Shouldn't we reward those? I mean I see a lot of cases where users tags their question `vba` instead of `vb.net` and trust me most of the time a quick retag is all that's needed **not** to cause 20 comments of type: *is it VBA or VB6 or VB.NET*? And that quick retag prevents a lot of further moderation required...Generally I agree with you and you got my ++ but also I just wanted to share my argument...

Comment: @Pimgd On the question I linked too, you said that you want to get 2k rep to get your edits approved imidiately, but you will not get rep for that afterwards

Comment: My goal is not rep, my goal is being allowed to fix typo's that I see without having to go through suggested edit queue. Having 2K rep achieves that goal. Once I'd have that rep level, well, I'd edit more. And (but feel free to tell me otherwise) I think my edits are good.

Comment: @vba4all My suggestion mustn't be the best, but I think that it's bad how it is actually

Comment: @Pimgd And without earning rep then - and your edits are good, but minor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tags are a significant *searchability* criterion. This means, incorrectly tagged questions should be cleaned up.

I don't see a problem in rewarding users, that do so correctly. There may be some dubious retaggings, but frankly speaking: If they aren't your area of expertise, why not skip the edit?

Because "I have no choice but approve them" is simply incorrect.

You do have another choice but accepting the edit, actually there's something like 3 possibilities, when you see a retagging in the review-queue:

1. **It's incorrect:**
   The retagging is simply *wrong* and you know it. You should reject such edits as incorrect.
2. **It's correct:**
   The retagging is correct, and you know it. This means it's an acceptable edit. You should approve or improve these edits.
3. **You aren't sure:**
   Because you can't be a pro in everything, you don't know whether the retag is appropriate. The solution is simple: You let other people handle it. Skip the edit.

Comment: Naturally, the first two have two sub-categories: It's incorrect and was good before vs. It's incorrect and needs polish and It's correct but needs more vs. It's correct and all that's needed.

Comment: @Deduplicator that's why you can edit whenever you reject or approve :)

Answer (score 8):

Tags on SO are the most valuable, and abused 'feature'. Good tags are very useful. Bad tags are worse than useless, they are harmful.

Any edit that removes a bad tag is improving the site.

A [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) question tagged as [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) should/would get fixed immediately by 'someone'. The mis-tagging is an obvious problem there because its effect is so high profile.

Why is correcting [spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spawn) any worse?

The reality is that mistagging on smaller tags is equally, if not more harmful because it exposes the question to the wrong crowds, in a way that takes longer to correct.

If someone is willing to spend the time to hunt down bad tags, and correct them, then they deserve more than just +2.....