# Dealing with edit suggestions that are useless and appear to be made for reputation gain only

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, reputation

Yesterday while being in the review queue and reviewing *Suggested Edits* I came across one user who did nothing to make a question more readable or increase the quality of the question.

The only thing he did was adding [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag to every single question that was about mobile(non necessarily *Android*!). After looking at his profile I noticed that he was in *Top 0.10% this week* as he got 200 reputation every day this week by just editing the questions(100 approved edits per day = 200 rep).

However, he only has 4 answers(with average score of 1) and 0 questions.

A few examples of those edits:

- [**how we can use mapbox-android-sdk library in android?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27720798/1047258) : this question needs more edits than only adding tags. It also needs some language and grammar fixes.
- [**Subversion in android studio**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28063008/1047258) : this question(IMHO) has NOTHING to do with *Android* itself. It specifically asks about *Android Studio*.

After some search found another of his edits that shouldn't even be approved(IMHO):

- [**cant change text value in jquery autocomplete**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27789075/1047258) : adding [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag to a question that doesn't even say anything about javascript(okay, jQuery IS a JS library, but there is already a [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tag)

And there are more.

I'm not against people gaining reputation quickly, but I'm absolutely against this kind of reputation gain. In my opinion, most rep should come from questions and answers, but not from edits. Also, [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reputation) says:

> The reputation is a measurement of a **user's contributions to the site**, and the extent to which the **community "trusts" that user with extra privileges**.

I do not trust this sort of users.

So my request would be:

1. Put a daily cap on maximum number of edit suggestions(for example 20, because we can only review up to 20 suggested edits per day anyway)

   1a. Or a daily cap on reputation gain from edits only.
2. Add some sort of punishment for such a users(for example: 5 rejected edit suggestions would lead to inability to suggest edits for a day. 7 rejects for 3 days. 10 rejects for a week. Or something similar)

Comment: I believe there are already repercussions if you suggest too many edits that get rejected. He'll reach 2k soon enough, any way, then he won't gain any rep from suggesting edits, meaning he actually has to contribute if he's doing it just for the rep.

Comment: The problem here is less about undue reputation (there are more worrying problems like users getting to 10k with just asking stupid trivial questions) than about a dumb and obvious cheating (which wouldn't make him gain so much rep anyway). **Just flag a review**.

Comment: I gave your post a slightly less inflammatory title.

Comment: Related: [Don't let users earn rep for retagging-only suggested edits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274875/dont-let-users-earn-rep-for-retagging-only-suggested-edits)

Answer (score 7):

There are already caps on the reputation gained from suggested edits only. The daily rep cap applies and only 1000 points **in total** can be earned from making suggested edits.

The proper way to deal with suggested edits that don't improve the post or are actively harmful (like misapplied tags) is to reject them. If you see a pattern of bad edits that are being consistently accepted, there may be a problem with the *reviewers* too. In that case flag one of the bad edits that has been approved for moderator attention and ask a moderator to intervene with the reviewers.

If suggested edits are being rejected, the user is [automatically banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337) from making more suggested edits for a limited period of time, to make them stop and reflect on how they are using the suggested edits system.

Comment: The fact that this user got the rep cap suggests that not enough of his edits were rejected. I believe we still have a robo-approver problem here.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: perhaps; feel free to find good examples of suggested edits that should not have been approved and flag those posts.